# Retornar o nome da propriedade DbQuery usando generics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, genéricos

Como consigo o nome da propriedade `DbQuery` usando generics?

Tenho a propriedade:

```
public DbQuery<Pessoa> ConsultarPessoas { get; set; }
```

E no meu repositório:

```
DataContext.Query<T>().FromSql("ConsultarPessoas");
```

Até aqui tudo bem. Agora preciso pegar o nome da propriedade via generics e setar no lugar de `ConsultarPessoas`.

Já faz tempo que estou pesquisando e ainda não consegui resolver.

```
?DataContext.Query<T>()
?DataContext.Query<T>().GetType()
?nameof(?DataContext.Query<T>())
```

Comment: E por que precisa disto? Quase sempre que vejo esse tipo de necessidade fica uma impressão que está usando algo errado e não precisa de fato, pode resolver de um outro jeito melhor.

Comment: @Maniero Costumo pegar o dbset no construtor: 
            dbset = DataContext.Set<T>()
e utiliza-lá quando solicitada: dbset.Find(id). Sendo que nunca  me preocupei em saber o nome da propriedade. Agora pretendo executar uma procedure com fromSql() e tenho que passa-la no parametro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que atendeu foi:

```
var result = DataContext.GetType().GetProperties()
.Where(x => x.PropertyType.FullName == 
dbQuery.GetType().BaseType.FullName).FirstOrDefault().Name
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Ronaldo,

Se você está usando dentro de uma classe genérica, o nome você tem à partir de:

```
typeof(T).Name;
```

Nesse contexto funcionaria algo do tipo:

```
DataContext.Query<T>().FromSql(typeof(T).Name);
```

Não sei se entendi bem o seu ambiente mas espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá @Thiago-Araújo na consulta retorna entidade: ?typeof(T).Name
"Pessoa"

?DataContext.Query<T>().FromSql(typeof(T).Name)
{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<Pessoa>}
    ElementType: {Name = "Pessoa" FullName = "System.Pessoa"}
    Expression: {value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.Pessoa]).FromSqlOnQueryable("Pessoa", value(System.Object[]))}
    Provider: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider}
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable